# this.Controls.RemoveByKey doesn't remove as expected

Tags: c#, winforms

Here's my code:

```
private void modeRadioChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton me = (sender as RadioButton);

        if (me == modeVerifyBtn)
        {
            label4.Visible = false;
            categoryField.Visible = false;

            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = "Select document..";
            button.Name = "selectDocBtn";
            button.Location = label4.Location;

            this.mode = SearchMode.VerifyCategories;
            this.Controls.Add(button);
        }
        else if(me == modeGscBtn)
        {
            this.Controls.RemoveByKey("selectDocBtn");
            this.mode = SearchMode.GetSkuCategories;
            label4.Visible = !label4.Visible;
            categoryField.Visible = !categoryField.Visible;
            categoryField.Enabled = false;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = this.skuResultsContainer;
        }
        else if (me == modeSearchCategoryBtn)
        {
            this.Controls.RemoveByKey("selectDocBtn");
            this.mode = SearchMode.SearchCategory;
            label4.Visible = !label4.Visible;
            categoryField.Visible = !categoryField.Visible;
            categoryField.Enabled = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = this.resultsContainer;
        }
    }
```

Checking the modeVerifyBtn creates the radiobutton as you would expect. However, when I check one of the other two radio buttons, it doesn't remove the radio button until I've clicked yet another radio button. i.e.

Step 1) Click modeVerifyButton (button is there, as expected
Step 2) Click modeGscBtn (button is still there, do not want this)
Step 3) Click modeSearchCategoryBtn (button disappears)

What's up with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you did not debug through this as the answer would be immediately apparent.

RadioButton.CheckChanged event is called on both Checked AND Unchecked events.  Your modeRadioChecked is being called twice every click.

Change your comparisons to:

```
if(me == modeVerifyBtn && modeVerifyBtn.Checked == true) {
} else if( me == modeGscBtn && modeGscBtn.Checked == true) { 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Step 1) Click modeVerifyButton (button is there, as expected

Only one event `Checked(CheckedChanged)` fired for modeVerifyBtn. Execution goes inside the first if block. Everything works fine.

> Step 2) Click modeGscBtn (button is still there, do not want this)

First `Unchecked(CheckedChanged)` event is fired for modeVerifyBtn. Execution goes inside the first if block. You add another `Button` to the form in the exact position of the initial button, giving an appearance that nothing changed, but it did. Now your form has two buttons.

Second `Checked(CheckedChanged)` event is fired for modeGscButton. Which removes one of the buttons added before. Now one still remains.

> Step 3) Click modeSearchCategoryBtn (button disappears)

First `Unchecked(CheckedChanged)` event fired for modeGscButton. The remaining button is removed.
Second `Checked(CheckedChanged)` event is fired for modeSeacrhCategory which removes a non-existant button again, no affect on the GUI.

Check the `Checked` property of RadioButtons before taking any actions of adding or removing the select button.